# Hide sensitive data from client side with static site

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, server, environment-variables

Recently I got a static website just `html`, `css`, and `js`. And there're so many keys that must be hidden before deploying, I tried to convert the project to use server using [parcel](https://en.parceljs.org/) but the project is too large to handle, So I think i have no options but storing them in a server-side and call it through api call.

I have two questions here:

1. Is calling api the only option i have?
2. If i call an api, how can i secure it?

Comment: Was hoping to see a good answer but I see that this question hasn't been answered for 9 months. It would be especially good if the answer included how to make use of Heroku.